# What data structure should I be using to store results returned by processes running in parallel?

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using the `multiprocessing` module to run a function in parallel. The processes that I run in parallel themselves have children which they run in parallel, so I cannot use the `pool` class except for the lowest level of children (i.e. those children that do not create any more children), since daemonic processes may not create children.

Due to this, I am using `Process`, and manually manage running and joining the processes.

Today, I spent quite a long time attempting to debug my code, as it seemed to be hanging but I could not understand where. After some debugging, I ended up finding out that the `multiprorcessing.Queue` object that I was using to store results was blocking indefinitely when one of my functions was attempting to put data into it. I am not particularly sure yet why it is blocking indefinitely, but I have confirmed that it is the issue since removing the `put` command allowed execution to continue (albet, without me getting any data).

Is `multiprorcessing.Queue` the right object to use  in order to store information returned by functions running in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocess systems are difficult to debug.  I suggest debugging all the lower-level functions througly, then add a sprinkling of multiproc to taste.

Because multiproc can be confusing, I suggest logging early and often.  If you log too much, it's easy to strip out the fluff.  But if there's a weird corner case that you can't see in the logs, then things can be ... difficult :)

The worker is logged with its name, and the parent is logged as "MainProcess". Normal stuff is logged as INFO, and terrible problems are logged with ERROR.

To emulate the "can't put stuff in my queue" error I created the output `Queue` to only hold one item.  There's other code that watches for this, and logs it specially.  (Change `if 0` to `if 1` to get the full code to run.)

Have fun!

```
import logging, multiprocessing, Queue

def myproc(arg):
    return arg*2

def worker(inqueue, outqueue):
    mylog = multiprocessing.get_logger()
    mylog.info('start')
    for job in iter(inqueue.get, 'STOP'):
        mylog.info('got %s', job)
        try:
            outqueue.put( myproc(job), timeout=1 )
        except Queue.Full:
            mylog.error('queue full!')

    mylog.info('done')


logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr(
    level=logging.INFO,
)
logger.info('setup')

inqueue, outqueue = multiprocessing.Queue(), multiprocessing.Queue()
if 1:                           # debug 'queue full!' issues
    outqueue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)
# prefill with 3 jobs
for num in range(3):
    inqueue.put(num)
# signal end of jobs
inqueue.put('STOP')

worker_p = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=worker, args=(inqueue, outqueue),
    name='worker',
)
worker_p.start()

worker_p.join()

logger.info('done')
```

Sample run:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] setup
[INFO/worker] child process calling self.run()
[INFO/worker] start
[INFO/worker] got 0
[INFO/worker] got 1
[ERROR/worker] queue full!
[INFO/worker] got 2
[ERROR/worker] queue full!
[INFO/worker] done
[INFO/worker] process shutting down
[INFO/worker] process exiting with exitcode 0
[INFO/MainProcess] done
[INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Comment: Dear shavenwarthog -- thanks a lot for this answer! Your tip about using the `logging` function seems especially helpful. Incidentally, I ended up doing something that is similar (but messier), in order to debug the problem I mentioned above. Now I know that my queue is getting blocked (and not because it is full!) when I attempt to put something onto it -- would you still recommend that I use queues to store the return values of multiproc functions?

Comment: P.S. I know it is not a `Queue.Full` error because I specified no maximum size for my queue.

Comment: You're very welcome! I find logging everything really valuable in tracking weird errors.
Now that I think of it, `Queue` is not good for storing data.  It has some overhead, in that it's monitored for changes and other processes are notified on push/pop.  Consider another worker that consumes data then writes it to a file or summarizes it or just sticks it in a `list`.

Comment: shavenwarthog, I had good results using the "Manager lists"; i.e. I created a [manager object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and used it to spawn a list which I passed around! So, I think in order to do stuff like what I was attempting to do, it's a good idea  to either use [shared memory objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) if the use-case is super simple, or managers, if the data objects to be chucked around are more complicated.